# Have Miktex and Texlive side-by-side

Tags: miktex, texlive, paths

I'm trying to have both MikTex and TexLive working on my Ubuntu Linux. Both the tex distros have been installed through apt-get. I know this is related to settings on the PATH variable. So what I did is:

Find TexLive executables location:

```
whereis texlive
```

That gives:

```
texlive: /usr/local/texlive /usr/share/texlive
```

so I added the first one to the PATH, by making sure it comes as first:

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH ; export PATH
```

Checking the PATH indeed gives:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/stefano/mpich-install/bin:/home/stefano/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

However, if I do:

```
tex --version
```

Still I get:

> MiKTeX-TeX 2.9.6300 (3.14159265) (MiKTeX 2.9.6700)
>   Copyright (C) 1982 by D. E. Knuth; all rights are reserved.
>   TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
>   using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
>   compiled with curl version 7.58.0; using libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
>   compiled with expat version 2.2.5; using expat_2.2.5
>   compiled with liblzma version 50020022; using 50020022
>   compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6636; using 2.6636
>   compiled with MiKTeX Core version 6.6704; using 6.6704
>   compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
>   compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 2.6700; using 2.6700
>   compiled with openssl version OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017; using OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
>   compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
>   compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11

And the same goes for pdflatex and xelatex.
Notice that:

```
which pdflatex
```

Gives:

```
/home/stefano/bin/pdflatex
```

Which is actually a symlink as I can see from:

```
ls -lah | grep pdflatex
```

Output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      22 mag 29 14:37 pdflatex -> /usr/bin/miktex-pdftex
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: the question seems more about shell (bash?) setup than about tex, so this may not be the best place to ask, however what does `type -a pdflatex` report?

Comment: also what does `pdflatex --version` report

Comment: ONT: what editor are you using?
OFT: do you wish to cross-compile or compile sequentially?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `pdflatex --version` gives exactly the same as `tex --version`reported above. Yes, I'm using bash shell. The command `type -a pdflatex` gives `pdflatex is /home/stefano/bin/pdflatex
pdflatex is /usr/bin/pdflatex`.

Comment: @naphaneal I'm using TexStudio. I guess sequentially. I would just want to compile through `pdflatex` (from terminal or from editor, whatever) either referring to MikTex or TexLive. So simply switch between distros as I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the miktex pdflatex in your path (it isn't clear why you would ever want both) `type -a pdflatex` showed you all the tex's you have in your path, and you only have two, the one in your home area which is symlinked to miktex and the ubuntu system texlive which will be the one in /usr/bin.

You added `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` to your path but (I assume) if you look there you will not see a tex, that is the default directory for the upstream texlive if you install it directly from the installer from TUG. If you use your linux distro's apt-get then you get a customised texlive that does not install there but in the system /usr/bin.

So you just need /usr/bin or /home/stefano/bin at the front of your path to switch between the two.

Comment: Now all makes sense and of course it works. Thank you for the explanation. If you want to know why I want both: it's just because I have a bug with a scientific journal template that I know in TexLive has already been fixed. I just did not want to uninstall MikTex, since, the other month, exactly happened the opposite.

Comment: @S.G.Rinaldo installing thousands of files in a completely separate tex distribution seems a somewhat extravagant way to update a .cls file that would only be a a few k in size, but perhaps I show my age, and disk space is cheap these days:-)